# Virtualmin Apache multiple ip addresses in one virtual server

Tags: apache, webmin, virtualmin

My server is:

> **Webmin Virtualmin Apache VPS in centos 7.**

I already have 5 different ip addresess in webmin.

And i have already created one virtual server in Virtualmin.

I need to connect all 5 ip addresses to this virtual server.

The virtual server must accept all domains: **must be default endpoint(domain) for all ip addresses.**

How can i do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want all addresses on the same VirtualHost, do this:

```
# Listen on all interfaces
Listen 80

# Default VH (first one in the configuration), for all connections on port 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Main domain
    ServerName www.example.com
    # Other domains, list all valid here
    ServerAlias example.com

    [... OTHER CONFIGURATION ...]

</VirtualHost>
```

If the requested domain matches any in `ServerName` or `ServerAlias`, it will use that VirtualHost.  If the requested domain does not match *ANY* of the other VirtualHost definitions, this one will still be used, if it is the first one in the configuration (i.e. it is the default).